# Joining on date or the next closest date after

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables I'm trying to join on date and account. For table one the field for date is continuous and is type string. Whereas for table two the field date has a portion of the date field as end of month only.

Edit: The sample I provided below is an example of tables I am working with. Originally I had only mentioned about joining the ID and Date fields but there are other fields in both tables that I am trying to keep in the final output. On a larger scale Table 1 has thousands of IDs with records continuously recorded daily across multiple years. In Table 2 this is similar but at some point the date field switched from only end of month data to the same daily date data as table one. The tables below have been updated.

A sample of the data set could be seen as follows:

```
Table1:
| ID | Date         |
| -- | ----------   |      
| 1  | "2022-01-30" |
| 1  | "2022-01-31" |
| 1  | "2022-02-01" |
| 1  |  "2022-02-02"|

Table2:
| ID   | Date         |Field_flag|
| ---- | ----------   | -------  | 
| 1    | "2021-12-31" |a         | 
| 1    | "2022-01-31" |a         |
| 1    | "2022-02-01" |a         |
| 1    | "2022-02-02" |b         |
| 1    |  "2022-02-03"|b         |

Desired result:
| table1.ID | table1.Date | table2.date| table2.Field_flag|
| --------  | ----------  | ---------- |  --------------- |  
| 1         | "2022-01-30"|"2022-01-31"| a                |
| 1         | "2022-01-31"|"2022-01-31"| a                |
| 1         | "2022-02-01"|"2022-02-01"| a                | 
| 1         | "2022-02-02"|"2022-02-02"| b                |
```

Are there any suggestions on how to approach this type of result?
I'm currently temp fielding and sub sampling the date fields into month and year as a temporary solution but would like something like an inner join as such to work.

```
Select table1.*
      ,table2.date as date_table2
      ,table2.Field_flag
FROM table1
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table2)
ON  table1.id = table2.id and (table1.date = table2.date or table1.date < table2.date)
```

Comment: Table 2 does not seem much different than table1. I do not see that it is displaying "only part of the month"

Comment: You tagged with both MySQL and PySpark.  Which one are you actually using here?

Comment: I am using SQLContext in a spark session, but there was not a tag for such

Comment: are there a lot of dates within each `ID` value? one approach could be to map all dates from the 2 dataframes within an ID and retain the ones closest to each other.

Comment: @samkart Yes, the example I proposed in my question was just a sample of what the data in the table looks like. I am currently adjusting my question for transparency.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this would be to use a correlated subquery to find the same or closest but greater date for each date in the first table.

```sql
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.Date AS Date_t1,
    (SELECT t2.Date FROM Table2 t2
     WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Date >= t1.Date
     ORDER BY t2.Date LIMIT 1) AS Date_t2
FROM Table1 t1
ORDER BY t1.ID, t1.Date;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Hello Tim, thank you for sharing this approach. This is what im looking for to help address my question and will try implementing it soon. To follow up i tried looking further into correlated subqueries and was unable to find a direct answer as to if I can pull in multiple fields. In my question I just simplified what the tables im actually working with are but would need multiple fields in table two to be joined in my final table. Is this possible with what you suggested? As I see it I could now just use the resulted table from this approach and do another join essentially on table two again.

Comment: ...then you didn't ask the right question, because the question you did ask apparently does not reflect the real problem.  Yes, you may add more correlated subqueries for other fields, using the same logic as I have used above.

Comment: My apologies, I did not want to ask to much and thought the root of my issue could be simplified down to the fields of the join. I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the optimal way but throwing it into the mix. We can join the second table twice - once for the daily dates and once for the month end dates.

```
data2_2_sdf = spark.sql('''
    select *,
        datediff(dt, lag(dt) over (partition by id order by dt)) as dt_diff_lag,
        datediff(lead(dt) over (partition by id order by dt), dt) as dt_diff_lead
        from data2
    ''')

data2_2_sdf.createOrReplaceTempView('data2_2')

# +---+----------+----+-----------+------------+
# | id|        dt|flag|dt_diff_lag|dt_diff_lead|
# +---+----------+----+-----------+------------+
# |  1|2021-12-31|   a|       null|          31|
# |  1|2022-01-31|   a|         31|           1|
# |  1|2022-02-01|   a|          1|           1|
# |  1|2022-02-02|   b|          1|           1|
# |  1|2022-02-03|   b|          1|        null|
# +---+----------+----+-----------+------------+

spark.sql('''
    select a.*, coalesce(b.dt, c.dt) as dt2, coalesce(b.flag, c.flag) as flag
    from data1 a
    left join (select * from data2_2 where dt_diff_lag>=28 or dt_diff_lead>=28) b
    on a.id=b.id and year(a.dt)*100+month(a.dt)=year(b.dt)*100+month(b.dt)
    left join (select * from data2_2 where dt_diff_lag=1 and coalesce(dt_diff_lead, 1)=1) c
    on a.id=c.id and a.dt=c.dt
    '''). \
    show()

# +---+----------+----------+----+
# | id|        dt|       dt2|flag|
# +---+----------+----------+----+
# |  1|2022-02-01|2022-02-01|   a|
# |  1|2022-01-31|2022-01-31|   a|
# |  1|2022-01-30|2022-01-31|   a|
# |  1|2022-02-02|2022-02-02|   b|
# +---+----------+----------+----+
```